# Replace words in string with words from list using python

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I'm working on creating a word cloud program in Python and I'm getting stuck on a word replace function. I am trying to replace a set of numbers in an html file (so I'm working with a string) with words from an ordered list. So `000` would be replaced with the first word in the list, `001` with the second, etc.

So below I have it selecting the word to replace `w` properly but I can't get it to properly replace the it with the words from the string. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
def replace_all():  
  text = '000 001 002 003 '
  word = ['foo', 'bar', 'that', 'these']
  for a in word:    
    y = -1
    for w in text:     
      y = y + 1
      x = "00"+str(y)
      w = {x:a}      
      for i, j in w.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
  print text
```

Comment: You're shadowing the `list` builtin by declaring a local variable of the same name. In general, it's a good idea not to do that, in case you find yourself needing the builtin later and you're getting strange errors.

Comment: Thanks that's a good point. I will fix that.

Comment: @NightMarcher Did you look at my solution ?

Comment: @eyquem I did and I think I should have been clearer when I made my original post....these methods work with simpler strings that I posted but when I tried to apply these to my HTML file it doesn't work as I expected. In the string listed below instead of changing all of the numbers 000, 001, 002 etc. with similar items from a list it only replaces them with the first item. This is an example of text from my HTML file:

Comment: @eyquem  EXAMPLE STING FROM HTML FILE: >>>text = '<p><span class="newStyle0" style="left: 291px; top: 258px">000</span></p> <p><span class="newStyle1" style="left: 85px; top: 200px">001</span></p> <p><span class="newStyle2" style="left: 580px; top: 400px; width: 167px; height: 97px">002</span></p> <p><span class="newStyle3" style="left: 375px; top: 165px">003</span></p>'

Comment: @NightMarcher Do I understand well if I understand from the above comments and from the comment you did after Larryware's answer that the problem occurs similarly with my solution and with Lattyware's solution ?

Comment: @NightMarcher I tried my solution with your text, having defined ``words = ['XXX-%04d-YYY' % a for a in xrange(1000)]`` and it works.

Comment: @eyquem I'm not sure how to use that method to replace the words from my ordered list.  I implemented that using your function below using regex and it grabs anything with a number and alters it according to XXX-%04d-YYY...maybe I am misunderstanding the implementation

Comment: @eyquem I get results that look like this: <p><span class="newStyleXXX-0000-YYY" style="left: XXX-0291-YYYpx; top: XXX-0258-YYYpx">XXX-0000-YYY</span></p>

Comment: @NightMarcher Yes it's the result I wanted. Isn'it what you want ? Replacing a string '000' by the element of **words** indexed 0, replacing a string '291' by the element of **words** indexed 291, etc... ? As I haven't your list **words**, I created mine. And to see well the transformations, I choosed to surround the replacing string with some X and Y and an hyphen. But that's purely arbitrary. If you use my code, use YOUR list **words**

Comment: @eyquem It is similar but I want to only replace the numbers 000-050 and not affect the px size.....with the above example I would replace 000 with "foo" 001 with "bar" 002 with "that" 003 with "these". None of the px variables are the same as the 000-050 numbers. I do not want to change any of the values in the text except the text that will be displayed when viewing the html file in a browser.  ie: all of the elements before the </span> tags in the file (ex: 000</span> = foo</span>)

Comment: @NightMarcher You should better have explained more what you wanted from the very beginning. I've edited my code according to your last explanations. If you want to replace portions just before ``</span>`` , it isn't necessary to take care of the range of the numbers there, a simple regex is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a really simple [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
>>> text = '000 001 002 003 '
>>> words = ['foo', 'bar', 'that', 'these']
>>> [words[int(item)] for item in text.split()]
['foo', 'bar', 'that', 'these']
```

Edit: If you need other values to be left alone, this can be catered for:

```
def get(seq, item):
    try:
        return seq[int(item)]
    except ValueError:
        return item
```

Then simply use something like `[get(words, item) for item in text.split()]` - naturally, more testing might be required in `get()` if there will be other numbers in the string that could get accidentally replaced. (End of edit)

What we do is split the text into the individual numbers, then convert them to integers and use them to index the list you have given to find words.

As to why your code doesn't work, the main issue is you are looping over the string, which will give you characters, not words. However, it's not a great way of solving the task.

It's also worth a quick note that when you are looping over values and want indices to go with them, you should use [the `enumerate()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) rather than using a counting variable.

E.g: Instead of:

```
y = -1
for w in text:
    y = y + 1
    ...
```

Use:

```
for y, w in enumerate(text):
    ...
```

This is much more readable and Pythonic.

Another thing with your existing code is this:

```
w = {x:a}      
for i, j in w.iteritems():
    text = text.replace(i, j)
```

Which, if you think about it, simplifies down to:

```
text = text.replace(x, a)
```

You are setting `w` to be a dictionary of one item, then looping over it, but you know it will only ever contain one item.

A solution that follows your method more closely would be something like this:

```
words_dict = {"{0:03d}".format(index): value for index, value in enumerate(words)}
for key, value in words_dict.items():
    text = test.replace(key, value)
```

We create a dictionary from the zero padded number string (using [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#formatexamples)) to the value, then replace for each item. Note as you are using 2.x, you'll want `dict.iteritems()`, and if you are pre-2.7, use the `dict()` builtin on a generator of tuples as dict comprehensions don't exist.

Comment: You're shadowing the `list` builtin by declaring a local variable of the same name.

Comment: Wow that is much easier than what I was doing. I guess I should have posted my string like this because there will be more text in the html file.   >>>text = '000 this is 001 some 002 text 003 '

Comment: @NightMarcher See my example at the end for a replace solution, although I will update the first solution to work with other text too.

Comment: @Lattyware: instead of your `get` function, you could use `words_dict.get(x,x)` in the listcomp.  `replace` is also dangerous because of the possibility of accidental replacements, but that's trickier to fix (and possibly outside the scope of the OP's assign-- er, problem.)

Comment: This method worked perfectly when I was using it to go through a string that I hard coded into the function. When I implemented this on an html file it replaces all of the numbers with the first item from the list. Any ideas why it would do that?

Comment: @Lattyware I implemented your changes to my code but it doesn't seem to work when it goes through the HTML file. I might not understand how to implement the get function that you added to your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

When working on texts , it is evident that one must think to regexes.

```
import re

text = text = ('<p><span class="newStyle0" '
               'style="left: 291px; '
               'top: 258px">000</span></p> <p>'
               '<span class="newStyle1" '
               'style="left: 85px; '
               'top: 200px">001</span></p> <p>'
               '<span class="newStyle2" '
               'style="left: 580px; '
               'top: 400px; width: 167px; '
               'height: 97px">002</span></p> <p>'
               '<span class="newStyle3" '
               'style="left: 375px; top: 165px">'
               '003</span></p>')

words = ['XXX-%04d-YYY' % a for a in xrange(1000)]

regx = re.compile('(?<=>)\d+(?=</span>)')

def gv(m,words = words):
    return words[int(m.group())]

print regx.sub(gv,text)
```